# IOS: Decrypting a message with public key received from webservice

Tags: iphone, encryption, public-key-encryption

I'm new to this topic so sorry if this is a stupid question :\

I'm trying to decrypt a message with a given public key. Both the message and public key is given from the webservice.

See the following code for how i currently do the decrypting:

```
 for (NSValue *refVal in keyRefs) {
    SecKeyRef p_key = NULL;
    [refVal getValue:&p_key];
    if (p_key == NULL) continue;

    size_t dataLength = encryptedData.length;
    size_t outPutLength = MAX(dataLength, SecKeyGetBlockSize(p_key));

    void *outPutBuf = malloc(outPutLength);
    if (outPutBuf) {

        //  Error handling
        OSStatus status = SecKeyDecrypt(p_key,
                                        kSecPaddingNone,
                                        encryptedData.bytes,
                                        encryptedData.length,
                                        outPutBuf,
                                        &outPutLength
                                        );


        NSLog(@"decryption result code: %ld (size: %lu)", status, outPutLength);
        NSLog(@"FINAL decrypted text: %s", outPutBuf);

        if (status == errSecSuccess) {
            break;
        }
    } else {

        //Error handling
    }
}
```

I get no errors, but the decrypted string is displayed like this (the correct output should be a JSON array):

```
decryption result code: 0 size:511)  
FINAL decrypted text: ÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀáÀá
```

Is it because I use the "SecKeyDecrypt" with a "public key" instead of a "private key"? In that case, what should i instead use for decrypting?

Thanks for any help regarding this!

EDIT: I'm using code from: http://blog.flirble.org/2011/01/05/rsa-public-key-openssl-ios/ to use the public key i get from the server (this is where "keyRefs" from the code snippet comes from)

Comment: A public key isn't for decryption. It's for encryption and signature verification. A private key is for decryption and signing.

Comment: The blog you linked doesn't use RSA for encryption at all. It uses a public key that's hardcoded into the client to verify a signature for licensing purposes. So what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: The public key itself is the public part of a RSA-key-pair stored on the server.

The encrypted message was created on the server by first JSON-encoding the object, then encrypted with the private-key with OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING, then base64-encoded, and then JSON-encoded again as a part of the final message.

The message and public key is stored on the client. What i want is to decrypt the message on the client by using the public key.

As i said, im not very good at this subject so i might have tried to do this the wrong way :\

Comment: @Madoc, you should read up on public key cryptography. Look into asymmetric vs symmetric encryption. What you are doing doesnt make sense. How is the user going to get the "public" key, are you going to sent it along with the encrypted data?

Comment: @PeteyB Yes, the "public" key is sent with the encrypted data. It is generated by openssl.

I know this is not the normal way to do it, but openssl RSA keys can be used for decryption. OpenSSL has a method to do this: "RSA_public_decrypt"

Comment: @Madoc, could you give us a description of what you are trying to accomplish? I don't think you are using the right tools here. Are you trying to hide information (ie encryption)? Or are you trying to verify that something came from you (ie signing)? Because what you are doing will not hide anything.

Comment: @PeteyB I've done som research and are scrapping this approach. We are now doing a more traditional (and correct) approach where server and cient exchange public keys. Thanks for all your suggestions and sorry that im a noob in this topic! :P

Comment: @Madoc, we've all been there. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, the public key is something someone else uses to encrypt data so that only someone with the private key can decrypt it.

The very definition of a public key is that you can give it to anyone.  You wouldn't want anyone to be able to decrypt anyone else's encrypted message would you?

It is impossible to tell from your code fragment where your private key is stored, or what the contents (or even class) of keyRefs is.

EDIT:  In response to above OP's comment. And clarification.

*"The public key itself is the public part of a RSA-key-pair stored on the server. The encrypted message was created on the server by first JSON-encoding the object, then encrypted with the private-key with OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING, then base64-encoded, and then JSON-encoded again as a part of the final message. The message and public key is stored on the client. What i want is to decrypt the message on the client by using the public key. As i said, im not very good at this subject so i might have tried to do this the wrong way"*

Thats not how public key cryptography works.  The server and client exchange public keys.  Then each of them use the other's public key to encrypt data sent to the opposite party. The receiving party always uses their own private key to decrypt the message.

If you want the server to generate an encrypted response, have the client pass their public key in the request, use that public key to encrypt the response, and then decrypt the response on the client with the client's private key.

Comment: The public key is stored on the server. In this case it is the server that encrypts the data, the clients are just supposed to decrypt them with the public key.

Comment: I'm using code from: http://blog.flirble.org/2011/01/05/rsa-public-key-openssl-ios/ to use the public key i get from the server

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your response. 

I get that this isn't how it normally is done. But by allowing the client to have both the private and public key it would defeat the entire purpose of what i am trying to do.

The client must not be able to reproduce the encoded messages. If the clients are able to reproduce the encoded messages they can "cheat" the system.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  If you can decrypt the message you can encrypt it.  In fact, you generate the 'public' key from the 'private' key.  Why would the server care what the client tells it?  Rethink your architecture and move all computation/business logic to the server.  Client requests update/roll/move whatever, server replies with the new count/number/position etc.

Comment: After some research, i'm going to go in another approach as you guys suggest. 

Now it will be a more traditional (and correct) approach where the client and server exchange keys as you suggested. Im setting this answer to correct since you come with many good suggestions. Thanks!